# Sending SMS to Dual SIM

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I have a script SMS android. This script is working properly, but I have a problem with the dual SIM card mobile phone.

My script was successfully sent messages to the SIM CARD 1. but not on the SIM card 2. Can anyone fix my script below?

```
try {
    System.out.println("MODEL:"+Build.MODEL);
    if (simID == 0) {
        name = Build.MODEL.equals("Philips T939") ? "isms0" : "isms"; //
        // for model : "Philips T939" name = "isms0"
    }
    else if (simID == 1) {
        name = "isms2";
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("can not get service which for sim '" + simID + "', only 0,1 accepted as values");
    }
    
    Method declaredMethod = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getDeclaredMethod("getService", new Class[]{String.class});
    declaredMethod.setAccessible(true);
    Object invoke = declaredMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{name});
    
    declaredMethod = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub").getDeclaredMethod("asInterface", new Class[]{IBinder.class});
    declaredMethod.setAccessible(true);
    
    invoke = declaredMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{invoke});
    Log.e("SimUtil", "send msg - " + smsText);
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
        invoke.getClass().getMethod("sendText", new Class[]{String.class, String.class, String.class, PendingIntent.class, PendingIntent.class})
        .invoke(invoke, new Object[]{toNum, centerNum, smsText, sentIntent, deliveryIntent});
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 18) {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        
        for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionId : SubscriptionManager.from(ctx).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()) {
            int subscriptionId2 = subscriptionId.getSubscriptionId();
            arrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(subscriptionId2));
            Log.e("SimUtil", "SmsManager - subscriptionId: " + subscriptionId2);
        }
        smsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(((Integer) arrayList.get(simID)).intValue()).sendTextMessage(toNum, null, smsText, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
    } else {
        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(toNum, null, smsText, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
    }
    return true;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("apipas", "ClassNotFoundException:" + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("SimUtil", "error 1");
    return false;
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    Log.e("apipas", "NoSuchMethodException:" + e.getMessage());
    Log.e("SimUtil", "error 2");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.e("apipas", "InvocationTargetException:" + e.getMessage());
    Log.e("SimUtil", "error 3");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e("apipas", "IllegalAccessException:" + e.getMessage());
    Log.e("SimUtil", "error 4");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("apipas", "Exception:" + e.getMessage());
    Log.e("SimUtil", "error 5");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
```

Here is the exception in the console:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xLXp.png]